# MailMessage.login_imap(self, connection, user, password) AssertionError: error not raised

Tags: python, exception, python-unittest, python-3.9, imaplib

I am trying to test my method login_imap() but got AssertionError: error not raised. Python 3.9
What do I do wrong?

```
    def login_imap(self, connection, user, password):
        try:
            if not connection.login(user, password):
                raise imaplib.IMAP4.error("Login failed!")
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error as error:
            print("Login failed!")
        return connection
```

test function:

```
    def test_afunction_throws_exception(self):
        user = '***'
        password = '***'
        server = '***'
        connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
        with self.assertRaises(imaplib.IMAP4.error) as e:
            MailMessage.login_imap(self, connection, user, password)
```

Comment: It simply means your asked your test to check that IMAP4.error was raised, and your function didn’t raise the error.  Why do you expect it to raise the error?

Comment: I run with an invalid login and expect to see that the caught exception gets into the unit test. Fixed it. It was necessary to return an error because an exception with the try except construct was handled unnoticeably for the unit test. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, assertRaises only checks for escaped exceptions, not ones that are caught.

Answer (score 0):

You used `try...except` to handle the raised exception in `login_imap` function. And, you didn't raise the exception again inside the `except` block. So in the test case, there is no exception raised. That's why `self.assertRaises()` fails.

As [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) doc says:

> Test that an exception is raised when callable is called with any positional or keyword arguments that are also passed to `assertRaises()`. The test passes if an exception is raised, is an error if another exception is raised, or fails if no exception is raised.

If you remove the `try...except`, the test case will pass. Besides, you could create a mock connection instead of a real one.

E.g.

`main_message.py`:

```py
import imaplib


def login_imap(self, connection, user, password):
    # try:
    if not connection.login(user, password):
        raise imaplib.IMAP4.error("Login failed!")
    # except imaplib.IMAP4.error as error:
        # print("Login failed!")
    return connection
```

`test_mail_message.py`:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock
import imaplib
from mail_message import login_imap


class TestMailMessage(TestCase):
    def test_login_imap_throws_exception(self):
        user = '***'
        password = '***'
        connection = Mock()
        connection.login.return_value = False
        with self.assertRaises(imaplib.IMAP4.error) as e:
            login_imap(self, connection, user, password)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test result:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Name                                              Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/70070717/mail_message.py            5      1    80%   10
src/stackoverflow/70070717/test_mail_message.py      15      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL
```